# Laptop HDD Swap

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, laptop, laptop-repair

I'm thinking of swapping the HDD from one non-functioning (dead screen) laptop to another. Assuming that the sizes of HDD all match up, along with the connection type, will this work? I understand I may need to reinstall Windows due to driver incompatibility issues, and I'm trying to recover the data on the HDD I'm putting in. Will I be able to recover this if I have to reinstall windows?

Comment: Depending on your hardware, you might also consider buying an [enclosure](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&DEPA=0&Order=BESTMATCH&Description=external+enclosure&N=-1&isNodeId=1). This way your old harddrive can now be used as an external hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

> Will this work?

TL;DR Yes, this will work.

Slight longer answer:
Is will work in almost all cases since almost all modern laptop use the same type of harddisks (2½ inch wide, 9.5mm high, SATA interface).

There are three notable exceptions:

1. Laptops from over a decade old might have a 44 pins PATA interface.
2. Laptops bought with ultra-high capacity harddisks (for their time) might have 2½ inch driver which are taller (10.5mm)
3. Ultrabooks or netbooks which might have rare 1.8" HDDs or flash soldered onto the motherboard (example: the Asus E701 Surf with a 2GB flash drive on the motherboard).

> I am trying to recover the data...

It will likely not boot without reinstalling windows, which might wipe the data you are after.

For recovery purposed try putting the disk from the broken laptop into an external case and connect that to a working system. (e.g. an external case with eSATA, Firewire or USB). Or connect it directly to the SATA port of a desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible to swap HDDs when the interface is the same. For data recovery you could use some kind of Linux-Live-CD but you need some place to copy the data to.

If the working computer has the same connection-type for its DVD-drive (e.g. both are SATA-devices), you could exchange the DVD-drive for the HDD to be recovered, boot into the working computer as usual and just copy all data from the second HDD.